# command line arguments with leiningen

Tags: clojure, command-line-arguments, leiningen

I have recently started out with clojure, and I am using leiningen to create a small project. I am having troubles in getting leiningen to behave with command line arguments. The following is my `src/project/core.clj`

```
(ns project.core
    (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
    (println (apply str args)))
```

and my `project.clj`

```
(defproject project "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write"
  :main project.core
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]])
```

Now when I run `lein run arg1 arg2`, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: arg1 in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5205)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5151)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3057)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:5371)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5190)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5151)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:4670)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:4328)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3173)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:5367)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5190)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5421)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:422)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:369)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: arg1 in this context
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:5677)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:5621)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:5584)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5172)
    ... 23 more
```

However, if I do a `lein uberjar` and then do `java -jar project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar arg1 arg2`, I get the correct output.

```
arg1arg2
```

It isn't very comfortable to have to create the uberjar to run it every time while development, is there a better way?

Comment: try lein run project.core arg1 arg2

Comment: @PheliX, yep, that gave some lead, it gives `class project.corearg1arg2`, but the uberjar gives `arg1arg2`... looks like some progress, but not quite usable yet. That, or I'm missing something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like it's caused by a bug that's been fixed in git. The fix will be in 1.4.2, which should be out in a few days. In the mean time, you can use workarounds discussed here: http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/a8160b23a5019a12

Comment: Yep, that works out. using `-m` to specify the module to run makes it work perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: FWIW the fix was released a few days ago.

Answer (score 6):

From [lein-run](https://github.com/sids/lein-run): "Args will be passed on as *command-line-args*"

So you will have to use those. The example on the site shows how. If you now what arguments you are passing you an also use :run-aliases to specify those in your project.clj. Again, the mentioned site has all the information.

My sample project.clj

```
    (defproject addressbook "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write"
  :main addressbook.core
  :run-aliases {:addressbook [addressbook.core -main "arg1"]}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]]
  :dev-dependencies [[lein-run "1.0.0"]])
```

And the test code:

```
(ns addressbook.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& [args]]
  (if args (println args)))
```

Both "lein run addressbook foo" as "lein uberjar" work for me.

Comment: Nope, if I remove `(:gen-class)` and the `& args` parts, and print `*command-line-args*`, I am getting `nil` with no arguments and a java stack trace with arguments. And without the gen-class, the uberjar never works

Comment: Weird, I just created a very simple project that only prints the *command-line-args*, but I don't use :gen-class and don't have a main method. Does the solution with the run-aliases work for you?

Comment: You don't have a main method? so you are not using leiningen? and no, defining a run-alias with two arguments and just printing the `*command-line-args*` still gives me a java stack trace..

Comment: You can use leiningen without having a main method. But I have added some sample code (with :gen-class and a main method) in my answer. Hopefully that makes it clear.

Comment: wait, I have to add `lein-run` as a dev-dependency? but I have a lein run already, is it different?